# Email already registered error message

Tags: support, status-completed, openid

I registered with Stack Overflow a long time ago with my gmail address. More recently, I did it again with another OpenID. I then switched OpenIDs to use my openIDs from Google and Yahoo.

I was able to configure my email (gmail) address on meta.stackoverflow.com, but not on stackoverflow.com, because I guess my gmail address was previously stored from my registration a long time ago.

Since I'm authenticated with OpenID, and since the Google variant of the OpenID protocol does allow the web site to retrieve the email address, is there any way to associate my email address with this account without getting the email conflict message?

Comment: Didn't want to ask the same question as Jay. So I'm posting comment instead of a fake answer...

I'm having the same problem between two accounts - I just want one but I mistakenly created two... - Marc could you email me too?

Answer (score 2):

Yup... let me take a look...

Interestingly, your old account was seen (logged in) yesterday; do you still have access to both? We can merge them easily enough; I just would like to confirm ownership (of both) first... I'll drop you an e-mail if that is OK?